# How to install msi package in the github-actions step on windows?

Tags: github-actions

I'd like to create basic github-actions job on windows that installs k6 (https://docs.k6.io/docs/installation#section-windows-msi-installer) as `msi` package downloaded from `https://dl.bintray.com/loadimpact/windows/k6-v0.25.1-amd64.msi`.

```
jobs:  
  k6_test:
    name: k6 on windows
    runs-on: windows-latest

    steps:
    - name: Install k6 from msi package
      run: ...

    - name: Check that it works
      run: k6.exe --help
```

Comment: did you check this other q and answer?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70036493/how-to-execute-msi-file-on-github-actions-windows-latest-runner

Answer (score 0):

The [windows environment](https://help.github.com/en/actions/automating-your-workflow-with-github-actions/software-installed-on-github-hosted-runners#windows-server-2019) comes with [`chocolatey`](https://chocolatey.org/) package manager. So just do:

```
run: choco --yes install k6
```

See: https://chocolatey.org/packages/k6