# How to execute MSI file on Github Actions (windows-latest runner)

Tags: windows, windows-installer, github-actions, powershell-cmdlet

### Context

I created a Github Actions workflow that generates a `.msi` file that I wan't to execute afterwards to test if the application is working as expected.

**The workflow implementation is as below**

```yaml
build-windows:
    runs-on: windows-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2.3.4
      - name: Create binary from branch
        run: |
          choco install make
          make build-windows
      - name: Generate msi
        shell: powershell
        run: .\.github\scripts\windows\gen-win.ps1
      - name: Install msi
        run: |
          echo "Start Msiexec"
          msiexec /qn /i "file.msi" /L*vx!
          echo "End Msiexec"
```

Basically this workflow creates the `.exe` file (`Create binary from branch` step), then use a script in powershell that generates the `.msi` file (`Generate msi` step), and finally try to install the `.msi` file (`Install msi` step).

---

### Issue

The problem occurs on the `Install msi` step, the runner logs only returns:

```
Start Msiexec
End Msiexec
```

... without showing any log, or creating the directories and files as the installation should do on the `$HOME` directory.

---

### What I tried

Using the default shell for windows-latest runner (which is `cmdlet`), I tried to run those commands in the workflow without success, using `"file.msi"` or `"path/to/file.msi"`:

```
msiexec /i "file.msi"
msiexec /qn /i "file.msi"
msiexec /qn /i "file.msi" /L*vx!
```

I'm not very familiar with the windows operating system, but for what I searched online, this msiexec command should work.

I also tried to install the `.msi` file generated manually on a windows 10 computer using those commands with success (so the generated `.msi` file is valid and working locally). However, it opens **another prompt window** automatically showing the installation and setup logs (it's not in the same terminal window) and I imagine this may not happen on Github Actions.

---

### Question

➡️ **How can I install this application from the `.msi` file through a command line on the windows-latest runner?**

Comment: You might get some ideas from https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments/issues/1704

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion @Lex Li. The manual step recommended in the issue you shared has already been implemented and deployed to production. I tried to add it even like this to be sure, but it didn't resolve my problem, the `msiexec` command still doesn't seem to be executed in the `Install msi` step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**After asking the same thing on the [Github Community forum](https://github.community/t/how-to-execute-msi-file-on-github-actions-windows-latest-runner/213122/4?u=guillaumefalourd), I got the following answer from [@Simran-B](https://github.community/u/Simran-B) (Github Advisory Council Member):**

> msiexec doesn’t seem to log anything to a terminal. If your MSI does
> (even if in a separate window), then it must be something that is
> specific to that MSI…
>
> What msiexec supports is to log to a file. Based on [Is there anyway
> to get msiexec to echo to stdout instead of logging to a file - Server
> Fault](https://serverfault.com/questions/434568/is-there-anyway-to-get-msiexec-to-echo-to-stdout-instead-of-logging-to-a-file/1007421#1007421),
> I successfully ran the following PowerShell script (using a Blender
> MSI as a test):

```
$file = "file.msi" 
$log = "install.log" 
$procMain = Start-Process "msiexec" "/i `"$file`" /qn /l*! `"$log`"" -NoNewWindow -PassThru
$procLog = Start-Process "powershell" "Get-Content -Path `"$log`" -Wait" -NoNewWindow -PassThru 
$procMain.WaitForExit() 
$procLog.Kill()
```

> I can’t recommend `/l*vx!`, because the forced flush for every log
> line makes things slow and the verbose output with additional
> debugging information can produce thousands of lines. Alternatively,
> you could log everything to a file without flushing, wait for
> `msiexec` to exit, and then print the file contents to the console in
> one go, which should be significantly faster (but you lose live
> logging).
>
> If I remember correctly, GitHub-hosted runners use elevated
> permissions by default. In my local test, I had to run the above
> script from an elevated PowerShell because the MSI tried to install to
> `C:\Program Files\`, which is not writable unless you have elevated
> permissions, and that made the installation fail without obvious log
> entry. If there’s something wrong with the `.msi` path, you may get an
> exit code of 1619 (`$procMain.ExitCode`), which is also not very
> intuitive. Another possible reason for nothing getting installed (at
> least apparently) can be that you don’t actually wait for `msiexec` to
> finish - the command immediately returns and the installation process
> runs in the background. You can use Start-Process with the `-Wait`
> option or get the handle with -PassThru and call `.WaitForExit()` on
> it to wait until it is done.

It worked for me! With those commands, I could execute the `.msi` file to install the software, then use it afterwards in my github actions workflow to perform my tests!